# Dog Sitting: drop-off vs pick-up

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology

This may sound like an odd question but I will be dog sitting for a friend for 2 weeks. The dog is 8 months old, very active, and hates parting with his owners.

Would it be best for me to go meet the dog in his own home and then take him with me? Or would it be better for his owner to come to my house with the dog for a bit and then leave?

I’m just wondering what dog owners think would be easiest for the dog to handle. I see pros and cons to both. I don’t want the dog to think I stole him away, but I also don’t want him to think his owner came to my house and abandoned him or forgot him. Any thoughts on the psychological/behavioral side of things here?

Comment: I don't think the dog would actually think you _stole_ him, but I get your point. I don't have hard facts nor experience, but I'd rather have the owners drop him off. Be prepared for many hours of whining, but don't get emotionally attached to that display of sadness. It will help if you play with him and overall keep him active/entertained. Do you have dogs of your own?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's much difference between either method, but I'm inclined towards the drop off method.

You should realize that dogs don't think in terms of "being stolen." They mainly think in terms of "good" and "bad." Food, petting, playing is all good. Being with the pack (the owners) is good, being separated from the pack is bad. So no matter **how** you separate the dog from his owners, it will always be categorized as bad.

But I think introducing a dog into a new environment with the owners is better than without, so the dog can discover his surroundings without being stressed from the separation.